# Convert split() into dict() after calling strip()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to create a dictionary of values resulting from a split() sequence without whitespace.

If I had a list of strings that were formatted like so:

```
lines = ['Item1 = A         Item2 = B         Item3 = C',
         'Item4 = D     Item5 = E']
```

I know how to get the *pairs* by whitespace >2 by:

`s = [y for x in lines for y in x.split('  ') if y]`

This returns another list of strings with the *pairs*:

`s = ['Item1 = A', 'Item2 = B', 'Item3 = C', 'Item4 = D', 'Item5 = E']`

So far so good. Now from here I need to break the *pairs* by the `=`, the left side is the `key` and the right side is the `value`. I can do this by:

`t = [y.split('=') for x in lines for y in x.split('  ') if y]`

This returns another list of strings with *broken pairs*:

`t = ['Item1 ', ' A', 'Item2 ', ' B', 'Item3 ', ' C', 'Item4 ', 'D', 'Item5 ', ' E']`

Now each item has either a trailing or a leading whitespace. This is easily fixed by updating that last list comprehension line to:

`t = [z.strip() for x in lines for y in x.split('  ') for z in y.split('=') if y]`

In order to make this a dictionary I know to call a generator expression:

`d = dict(y.split('=') for x in lines for y in x.split('  ') if y)`

But this keeps that trailing or leading whitespace with the `key` and `value`. If I were to add the `z.strip()` I get the error:

`ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required`

**Question:**

> How can I use the `dict()` generator and `strip()` whitespace from the `split('=')` call at the same time? Or am I forced to `strip()` after the `dict()` call?

Comment: You should look at dedicated parsers such as `configparser` (standard library) or `pyparsing` (third-party).

Comment: you could simply `split` on `' = '` instead of `'='` to avoid `strip`ing.

Comment: Don't edit questions with an answer. Answers belong in answers. Accepts are enough to signal that the problem is solved.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I edited with an updated answer; the solution I used was not identical to the posted answer. Difference seems like a good reason to post.

Comment: In that case add an answer of your own down below, where it belongs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
s = ['Item1 = A', 'Item2 = B', 'Item3 = C', 'Item4 = D', 'Item5 = E']

#b = dict([x.split(' = ') for x in s])  # list comprehension: slightly faster.
b = dict(x.split(' = ') for x in s)     # generator expr.   : memory efficient.

print(b)  # {'Item3': 'C', 'Item1': 'A', 'Item4': 'D', 'Item5': 'E', 'Item2': 'B'}
```

Comment: Excellent solution! The only slight improvement I need is to add a `.strip()` or `.rstrip()` to remove any `'\n'` characters.

Comment: Found the correct solution sequence. I've updated my post. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over `t` using [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) with a step of `2`:

```
>>> t = [z.strip() for x in lines for y in x.split('  ') for z in y.split('=') if y]
>>> t
['Item1', 'A', 'Item2', 'B', 'Item3', 'C', 'Item4', 'D', 'Item5', 'E']

>>> dict((t[i], t[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(t), 2))
{'Item2': 'B', 'Item3': 'C', 'Item1': 'A', 'Item4': 'D', 'Item5': 'E'}
```

To fit it all in one line you could also write:

```
>>> d = dict(tuple(k.strip() for k in y.split('=')) for x in lines for y in x.split('  ') if y)

>>> d
{'Item2': 'B', 'Item3': 'C', 'Item1': 'A', 'Item4': 'D', 'Item5': 'E'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could identify a pattern to match with a regex, then you could use `re` and `itertools` to handle the `dict` creation

```
>>> import itertools
>>> import re
>>> dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable(re.findall('(\w+\d+) = (\w+)', line) for line in lines))
{'Item1': 'A', 'Item2': 'B', 'Item4': 'D', 'Item3': 'C', 'Item5': 'E'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my go at it:

```
lines = ['Item1 = A         Item2 = B         Item3 = C',
         'Item4 = D     Item5 = E']
gen = (piece for line in lines for piece in line.split() if piece != '=')
d = dict(zip(gen, gen))
print(d)
>>> {'Item4': 'D', 'Item2': 'B', 'Item1': 'A', 'Item3': 'C', 'Item5': 'E'}
```

Or if you like to cram things into one line:

```
d = dict(zip(*[(p for l in lines for p in l.split() if p != '=')] * 2))
```

Instead of splitting by double spaces and then by equals, just split by whitespace in general and then remove equals tokens. Then pass the generator twice to `zip` to generate the pairs for `dict`.

The drawback of this solution is that it requires to have always whitespace around the equals symbols.

Comment: using `split` as a variable name is confusing.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yeah you're probably right I've changed it.