# Python Pandas: why are some data missing from my dict when I get data from JSON-formatted text via dict(line.strip().split(None, 1)?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to get data (property names and values) from JSON-formatted files.  I can get what I need from the files as a list of strings.  I.e., this always works:

```
f = open("f.txt", "r")
data = json.load(f);
f.close()
get = data["payload"]["blob"]["rawLines"]
```

so that when I print "get" I see something like this (below) that contains all of the values and property names I need:

```
get ['        name   property1                  ', '            98.00000        property2                             ', '             3.00000        property3                     ', '           500.66300        property4                                                                        ', '         -50000.9999        property5                                      ', '           100.45200        property6                                    ', '            59.75258        property7                                         ', '             9.66543        property8                                         ', '             0.00000        property9         ', '           100.07655        property10                                       ', '             0.00000        property11                           ', '             0.00000        property12                                            ', '             0.00000        property13                    ', '             0.00000        property14                    ', '             8.88888        property15                                           ', '             1.00000        property16                                               ', '             0.00000        property17 ...
```

However, when I then make a dict via a strip and split:

```
mydict = dict(line.strip().split(None, 1) for line in get)
```

some of the property name-values pairs are missing.  For example, property16 and its value are always missing.

I can't post the data but am hoping that someone may know of a more robust method for dealing with the strip and split step.  Today I have been looking at previous posts (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547263/convert-split-into-dict-after-calling-strip) one) but have not been getting far.

---

The solution from @Tim Roberts has solved the fundamental problem.  By using

```
mydict = dict(reversed(line.split(None, 1)) for line in get)
```

I get all of the property name–value pairs that were previously missing.

There is one minor issue.  The commas persist.  So when I turn the dict into a dataframe

```
mydataframe = pd.DataFrame(mydict.items(), columns=["name", "value"])
```

I get

```
                                             name            value
0                            Methane                    CH4
1   Thing2word1 Thing2word2                        ...         25.07700
2   Thing3word3 Thing3word3                 ...          11.33000
...
```

Is there a way to get rid of the commas so that there are only two columns, the property name and value?  Thank you.

Comment: You are making the first word the key and the second word the value, but your keys are not unique.  Remember, if you have "1.0000" in a dict, adding another "1.0000" later will overwrite it.  Did you want a list of 2-element tuples instead of a dict?  Or did you want the property name as the key?

Comment: @TimRoberts, I did not realize I was doing that!  I'm new to dealing properly with dicts.  My files are long, so it's very likely that some values are identical.  Thank you so much for catching that.  Yes, I do want the property name as the key.  My property names can be made up of several words and symbols (like "-" and "/").  I see you posted an answer but it was deleted before I read it.

Comment: I deleted it because it was wrong.  I fixed it below.  If your names contain spaces, then you DO need the `split(None,1)`.

Comment: What commas? There are none in your sample data... There will still be spaces in the property names though, I think you actually want `mydict = dict(line.strip().split(None, 1)[::-1] for line in get)`

Comment: @Nick, thank you, that did it!  I was referring to commas in my question update.  I need to figure out why your solution works to get rid of them.  Would you like to add your response as an answer?

Comment: @Ant that's why I'm confused, you referred to commas but I can't see any in the question anywhere, so I don't know why the solution works because I can't test it... so I don't feel comfortable posting it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need "strip" if you do the default split.  I suspect what you want is to reverse the key and value, like this:

```
mydict = dict(reversed(line.split()) for line in get)
```

Output:

```
{'property1': 'name', 'property2': '98.00000', 'property3': '3.00000', 'property4': '500.66300', 'property5': '-50000.9999', 'property6': '100.45200', 'property7': '59.75258', 'property8': '9.66543', 'property9': '0.00000', 'property10': '100.07655', 'property11': '0.00000', 'property12': '0.00000', 'property13': '0.00000', 'property14': '0.00000', 'property15': '8.88888', 'property16': '1.00000', 'property17': '0.00000'}
```

Comment: thank you.  I'm now seeing the properties that were missing.  I do have one outstanding problem, but don't want to impose.  It's that the commas are preserved between the two columns (property names and values).  I will update my question with the details.  Also, you were right that I do need split(None, 1) and not split().